# How to add an "Add Button"- Button

Tags: swift, xcode

I'm looking to make a button which creates new buttons.
So there are already 3 buttons created by me with ViewController.
And on the bottom should be a "create new button" button. So the user can create as many buttons as he wishes. And every new button should be stacked under each other.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/yPrng.jpg

Here is how I build it on ViewController.

Answer (score 0):

You have some ways to achieving this result. You can create a stack view and push the buttons to it. You can programatically add buttons to the screen by creating new UIButtons every time the users click the add button, or you can create a table view, and add a new cell every time the user clicks it. This last approach already supports scrolling (For when your user clicks tens of times, you'll need to able to scroll the screen so they can see the buttons outside the visible frame). In case you choose to go with the first or second, don't forget to add an UIScrollView to your View.

The steps to get this result with a tableview (3rd approach are):

1. Create a UITableView in the view controller's storyboard.
2. Set the UITableView datasource and delegate to the view controller
3. Create a UITableViewCell inside the UITableView, and set its identifier to something related to cell, like "buttonCell", for example.
4. Add a UIButton to this newly created UITableViewCell, and pin the constraints accordingly.
5. in the View Controller .swift file, create an outlet for the UITableView
6. in the tableView delegate cellForRowAt, don't forget to use the right identifier (in our example, "buttonCell").

if you get lost somewhere in the steps listed above, check some tutorials to create a tableview, such as: https://www.ralfebert.de/ios-examples/uikit/uitableviewcontroller/

Comment: How can I do it the second way? "You can programatically add buttons to the screen by creating new UIButtons every time the users click the add button" - Or where can I find the solution for that? I was looking on youtube but couldn't find a videos that helps me. Thanks for helping

Comment: Is it possible to do it with a loop? By clicking on the add Button.

Comment: You can create a variable to store the y position of the initial button, and with every click Instantiate a new UIButton (takes a CGRect as parameter, and the y parameter, inside the CGRect, is going to be this variable), than you increment the y and keep going.